# ROR 3.1 + Cucumber => Routes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1

It would be greatly appreciated if you could assist with the following issue/act of inexperience. I have searched the usual suspects (google, stackoverflow, groups, etc) to no avail and if I have missed something blatantly obvious my apologies.

I am starting to learn ROR3.1 plus cucumber through the following online tutorial at http://ridingrails.net/rails-3-cucumber-started-outside-in-testing/ which seems great except for my lack of success.

All good and well except that for some reason the one step is beyond my reach, if you could assist it would be greatly appreciated.

**The Feature:**

```
Feature: User manages agents
  Scenario: User adds a new agent
    Given I go to the new agent page
    And I fill in "Name" with "Alex"
    When I press "Create"
    Then I should be on the agent list page
    And I should see "Alex"
```

**The Error:**

Feature: User manages agents

```
Scenario: User adds a new agent              # features/agent_management.feature:2
Given I go to the new agent page             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:48
And I fill in "Name" with "Alex"             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:60
When I press "Create"                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:52
Then I should be on the agent list page      # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:187
  expected: "/agents"
       got: "/" (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:190:in `/^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/'
  features/agent_management.feature:6:in `Then I should be on the agent list page'
And I should see "Alex"          # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:105

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/agent_management.feature:2 # Scenario: User adds a new agent
```

**The guilty parts according to me => paths.rb:**

```
def path_to(page_name)
  case page_name

  when /^the home\s?page$/
    '/'
  when /the agent list page/
    agents_path
  ...
```

The web_steps.rb file is the standard one generated as described by the tutorial. Here is the function just in case:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should be on (.+)$/ do |page_name|
  current_path = URI.parse(current_url).path
  if current_path.respond_to? :should
    current_path.should == path_to(page_name)
  else
    assert_equal path_to(page_name), current_path
  end
end
```

**Additional details** that might assist:

> ruby -v => ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
>
> rails -v => Rails 3.1.0.rc5
>
> cat /proc/version/ => Linux version 2.6.38-10-generic
>   (buildd@vernadsky) (gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) )
>
> cat /etc/issue => Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l

If there are any other details required please let me know as I am stumped.

Thanking you in advance for any assistance.

**EDIT**
rake routes output below:

```
root        /                                 {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
agents GET    /agents(.:format)               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"agents"}
POST   /agents(.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"agents"}
new_agent GET    /agents/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"agents"}
edit_agent GET    /agents/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"agents"}
agent GET    /agents/:id(.:format)            {:action=>"show", :controller=>"agents"}
PUT    /agents/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"agents"}
DELETE /agents/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"agents"}
```

controller:

```
class AgentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @agents = Agent.all
  end

  def new
    @agent = Agent.new
  end

  def create
    @agent = Agent.new(params[:agent])
    if @agent.save
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

routes:

```
Outsidein::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "home#index"
  resources :agents

end
```

Comment: so what is the problem? if your scenario fails it means your app doesn't work properly

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out how to resolve the issue. My understanding (limited) is that somewhere during the routing process cucumber/rails expects to be directed to the "/agents" path but in reality the system directs to the "/" path. Thus from my understanding the issue is a routes directing issue and I can't figure out where/how to resolve this. Please let me know if this makes sense or whether I am missing something so simple?

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this scenario manually? Error tells you that after you press "Create" button you should be redirected to `http://yourhost:port/agents` however it does not happen you're redirected to `http://yourhost:port/`

Comment: Ah the classic manual intervention. No I have not, but will try and provide feedback. I tried to keep to the whole BDD method of first getting cucumber to work before going through manual process. Thanks for the assistance so far, much appreciated.

Comment: it'd be good to see the routes + controller

Comment: I have tried the manual option and when creating the agent it still pops through to the "/" path. I have added the routes file contents, agent controller file contents and the output of the rake routes command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your create action, when you successfully save the model, it redirects to the root_path - not the agents_path ... so you will need to change that path in the action, or your expectation in the features.

Comment: it makes so much of sense! Will test.